# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS for a single folder only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following that redirects all HTTP:// requests to HTTPS:// (see below). However, I would like to do this ONLY for 1 folder called "account".

So only requests to http://www.mydomain.com/account would turn into https://www.mydomain/account.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Can anyone help?

--- UPDATE ---

note that I would also like to ensure all requests outside of this folder remain normal HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: If you have the cert for the domain why don't you just push all traffic over to https?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^account(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

The `(.*)` pattern that you had before matches *every* request, the `^account(.*)$` pattern only matches requests that start with `/account`

---

To prevent other requests from using SSL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^account http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin. Would if match a folder like this: http://www.mydomain.com/something/account? I'd like to insure it matches just the account folder in the root.

Comment: @Andrew The `^` ensures that is has to be at the *beginning* of the request URI.

Comment: I see one little issue so I updated my question. I also need all requests outside of this folder to remain regular HTTP and not HTTPS. Any ideas?